# redcloth (MissingSourceFile) - new problem after Heroku changed to bundler 1.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, heroku, bundler, redcloth

Our app had been working.  Now I just pushed some new code into staging on Heroku for the 1st time after they moved to bundler 1.0.7.  Now our app crashes and I got this error message -

```
/usr/ruby1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require': no such file to load -- redcloth (MissingSourceFile)
```

We're on Rails 2.3.8.

Here is part of the Gemfile -

```
gem 'rails',   '2.3.8', :require => nil
gem 'RedCloth',                   :require => 'redcloth'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on Heroku and this is what I have :

```
gem 'RedCloth', '4.2.3'
```

Comment: This works. It seemed like that '4.2.6' was causing the problem.  By specifying 4.2.3 fixed the problem.  Thanks, Trip!